# shutdown Interlock protected routine

Tags: c#

My timer routine is protected from multi-entrance like below:

```
private void TimerCallback(object state)
{
    if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref currentlyRunningTasksCount, 1, 0) != 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    // some job is being done here

    Interlocked.Decrement(ref currentlyRunningTasksCount);
}
```

There is also timer shutdown procedure, where I want to make sure that the timer is not in the middle of something. So I do the following:

```
public void Shutdown()
{
    aTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
    for(;;)
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref currentlyRunningTasksCount, 0, 0) == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Question - is it proper way to check in Shutdown or I should use `Interlock.Read` and compare with 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a lock for that. It supports both cases easily and without busy waiting.

You can use `if (!Monitor.TryEnter(...)) return;` to exit the tick handler.

To wait for the timer to exit you do `lock (...) { }`.

You need to set a boolean field to signal that the timer is shut down. There can be arbitrarily many tick events be fired *after* the call to `Change`. (For the same reason your existing `Shutdown` code does not actually shut down the timer.)

All of this can be simplified away, though:

```
async Task RunMyTimerAgent() {
    while (true) {
     await Task.Delay(...);
     Work();
     ThrowIfCancelled();
    }
}

var timer = RunMyTimerAgent();
//cancel the timer here
timer.Wait(); //Wait till shutdown.
```

This loop has time drift, though.

Comment: `lock` is so much easier to understand... Also it may be whole point of OP - to create code that can be read/understood by least number of people :) . BTW I think in loop with `Task.Delay` is much more obvious  to fix time drift as one can adjust delay every time (unlike regular timer that usually runs with fixed delay and drifts too).

Comment: sorry, what that `while` should replace? Current shut down routine? Could you please elaborate more on that mechanism?

Comment: The while thing would replace the entire timer.

Comment: How to fix the drift? This approach looks very simple and interesting to me.

Comment: @Pablo you fix it by calculating how long you need to wait each loop then plugging that number in for the `...` on the `await Task.Delay(...)`. Here is a rough example `var waitTime = GetNextFireingTime() - DateTime.UtcNow; await Task.Delay(waitTime < TimeSpan.Zero ? TimeSpan.Zero : waitTime);`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I recommend TickCount. DateTime.UtcNow can change arbitrarily and cause the loop to essentially stop or execute early. Microsoft made a push to replace all kinds of internal timeouts with UtcNow in the BCL. I think it happened with 4.5.